# Distribute iOS app on in multiple stores without translating

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an English version of our iOS app. I've been asked to get it onto all App Store territories so our staff members in foreign countries can download it.

Will Apple allow us to submit an app to multiple territories if it hasn't been fully translated into that language? Or will they simply reject it?

I can't see an answer to this question in their documentation.

Comment: Please don't add signatures and salutations to your questions. They are considered noise on Stackoverflow. The same goes for things like 'cheers', 'thanks in advance' etc.

Comment: Yes, you can have your app available in all App Stores without localization.

Comment: Thanks @rokjarc. Is there anything I need to be aware of, or is it as easy as selecting all the territories in itunes connect?

Comment: It is as easy as selecting all the territories while publishing the app.

Comment: If this is a corporate appliaction (ment to be used solely by employees of one company) you might want to consider in-house distribution option though: https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've been submitting apps for all territories with only english language both in app and in descriptions.